# CPP won't generate text?

Tags: c++

I have some CPP code to generate Lorem Ipsum style text. It works when I ask it for one sentence at a time, but when I tell it to mass generate sentences it generates tons of sentences that are just spaces and then periods. Here's the code (modified for confidentiality):

```
    srand(time(NULL));
    string a[9327] = {"Str1", "Str2", "Str3" . . .};
    int loop_1 = 0;
    int loop_2 = 0;
    while (loop_2 <= 100000) {
    while (loop_1 <= (rand() % 38) + 2) {
        int value = rand() % (9327 - (rand() % (9327 - (rand() % (9327 - (rand() % 9327))))));
        cout << a[value] << " ";
        loop_1 = loop_1 + 1;}
    cout << "\b. ";
    loop_2 = loop_2 + 1;
    }
```

I'm sorry if this is an incompetent question. I'm a conlanger/composer normally but I had to throw together some code for a project––so I'm still just barely learning C++.

Comment: What does "absolutely gives out on me" mean? Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted. Repeated low-quality questions may result in a temporary ban from asking new questions.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll rephrase that and then read these. I tried to cut the example as much as possible, but concision has never been my strong spot. I'll make the requested changes. Thank you for your time! (I had read them beforehand but I'll reread them to see if I missed anything important.)

Comment: Can you explain what does that weird formula that involves not just one, but four calls to `rand()` is supposed to accomplish? What does that mean?

Comment: Thank you XD. I'll toss that in as the answer. It's based off of an algorithim I made in a different software where you said random(a, random(a, b)) as many times as necessary to weight the list toward "a," but the rand() % a function works in a very different way.

Comment: No, don't post that as an answer, this is not what answers are for. You have far more pressing issues to deal with, such as showing a [mre]. Can you answer the following question: can everyone else in the world cut/paste what's shown in the code, into an empty file, then compile, run, and reproduce your results? Unless your answer is "yes" this is not a [mre]. The answer is, of course, "no". The shown code will not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I mean, this code doesn't make a lot of sense but to answer the question, note that the only way the inner loop can not issue random strings is if it never runs and it will not run if `loop_1` is greater than `(rand() % 38) + 2` which is a random number from 2 to 40. Once `loop_1` is greater than 40 the inner loop can never run, because `loop_1` only increases.

But anyway, before that occurs, if you want the inner loop to definitely run then test that it does ... Also might as well get rid of `loop_2` because it isn't doing anything once `loop_1` is greater than 40.

Replacing 9327 with 7, I get

```
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    string a[7] = { "aaaaaaaaaa ", "bbbbbbbb ", "ccccccccccccc ", "dddddddd ", "eeeeeeeeeee ", "ffffffffff ", "ggggggg "};
    int loop_1 = 0;
    while (loop_1 < 40) {
        auto num = (rand() % 38) + 2;
        if (loop_1 > num) {
            continue;
        }
        while (loop_1 <= num) {
            int value = rand() % (7 - (rand() % (7 - (rand() % (7 - (rand() % 7))))));
            cout << a[value] << " ";
            loop_1 = loop_1 + 1;
        }
        cout << "\b. ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes a ton of sense as to what I was doing wrong. My random number generator was terrible and the looping system was breaking for higher values. I got it working now.